# Stuck after reset all settings + Home button doesn't work

Tags: iphone, ios

Thanks for reading. I'm in a bit of a pickle here. I have a jailbroken iPhone 6 on 9.3.3 that is stuck at the Apple Logo with the progress bar below it at about 5%. On top of this problem, my home button is out of commission due to a faulty repair by yours truly. That means a hard reset is out of the question. Here's what I've tried:
Letting the battery die- First shows Apple logo and then shows bar and just loads up to 5% again and stops.
Connecting to iTunes- Doesn't recognize my phone (although it does recognize other phones)
Holding volume up when booting after letting the battery die- Just doesn't work
Any help is appreciated. I really need my Phone back.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will work.. but you can try to google a program that is made to put iPhone in recovery mode. Then you could restore it with iTunes. There's many programs out there but I'm not sure it would work if iTunes won't even recognize it. Best bet is to get that home button working some how.